# NGRX Entity: How to use it within template?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I followed a tutorial on how to implement an NGRX store with an NGRX entity.

Everything seems to work (as far as I can tell using the dev-tools-extension). However, I don't know how I should/can iterate over the result in the template.

The template:

```html
<h3>MOVIES</h3>

  <ng-container *ngIf="movies$">
      <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let movie of (movies$ | async); let i = index">
          <li>
            {{movie?.title}}
          </li>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </ng-container>
```

The component:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-movies',
  templateUrl: './movies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movies.component.scss']
})
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {

  movies$: Observable<Dictionary<Movie>>;

  constructor(private store: Store<MovieState>) {
    this.store.dispatch(loadMovies());
    this.movies$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectMovieEntities))
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

And for completeness, the reducer:

```typescript
const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll,
  selectTotal
} = fromReducer.adapter.getSelectors();

export const getMovieState = createFeatureSelector<fromReducer.State>(fromReducer.moviesFeatureKey);

export const selectMovieEntities = createSelector(getMovieState, selectEntities);
```

The Error-Message:
[image]

I'm wondering if I should "map" the result set first or what else is best practice here.

Hope for your help!

Comment: Could you add your state interface or at least the part selected by selectEntities selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectEntities` returns the entities state as a dictionary (id is the key).
If you just want the entities (as an array), use the `selectAll` selector.

```
export const selectMovieEntities = createSelector(getMovieState, selectAll);
```